# c# Pinvoke with StringBuilder returns different results for the same method

Tags: c#, encoding, pinvoke, stringbuilder

So I noticed something very odd that I failed to fix. I'm sure it's just a stupid encoding error, but trying to encode the results differently didn't help me either.

The Problem:

When I Pinvoke the function `PathYetAnotherMakeUniqueName` from the Shell32.dll via `DllImport`

```
[DllImport("shell32.dll", EntryPoint = "PathYetAnotherMakeUniqueName", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
internal static extern bool PathYetAnotherMakeUniqueName2(
                System.Text.StringBuilder pszUniqueName,
                string pszPath,
                string pszShort,
                string pszFileSpec);

[...snip...]

System.Text.StringBuilder pszUniqueName = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
PathYetAnotherMakeUniqueName2(pszUniqueName, "Foo", "Bar", "Test");
Console.WriteLine(pszUniqueName); // Output : Foo\Bar
```

Or via the `LoadLibrary` approach

```
internal delegate bool dPathYetAnotherMakeUniqueName([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]System.Text.StringBuilder pszUniqueName, string pszPath, string pszShort, string pszFileSpec);
static dPathYetAnotherMakeUniqueName PathYetAnotherMakeUniqueName;

[...snip...]

hCurModule = LoadLibrary("shell32.dll");
IntPtr pFunction = GetProcAddress(hCurModule, "PathYetAnotherMakeUniqueName");
PathYetAnotherMakeUniqueName = (dPathYetAnotherMakeUniqueName)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pFunction, 
            typeof(dPathYetAnotherMakeUniqueName));

System.Text.StringBuilder pszUniqueName = new System.Text.StringBuilder ();
PathYetAnotherMakeUniqueName(pszUniqueName, "Foo", "Bar", "Test");
Console.WriteLine(pszUniqueName); // output: "?o\?r???o
```

As you can see I get two only vaguely similar outputs. I tried changing the `MarshalAs` attribute or encoding the `StringBuilder`s' contents in ASCII, Unicode or UTF7,8,32 etc., but the output did not change.
Without using `MarshalAs` (which seems to work for some other methods that require the `StringBuilder`) I get a stack imbalance exception.

Did anybody encounter this problem before?

Comment: This begs the question why would you want to do it via `LoadLibrary`?

Comment: You must set the Capacity of the StringBuilder to MAX_PATH, 260.  The delegate declaration is wrong, all the strings are Unicode.  Do not ignore the return value, throw an exception when you get *false*.  There is no point in using LoadLibrary, the pinvoke marshaller already does that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your input strings are being marshalled as `LPStr`. The [default marshalling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h(v=vs.110).aspx) for strings is `UmanagedType.LPTStr`, which is platform dependent and is resolved to either `LPStr` or `LPWStr`. On your platform it is being resolved to `LPStr`, I'm assuming it is because the default `CharSet` is `CharSet.ANSI`, and you do not specify a different one for the manually loaded function (would welcome authoritative confirmation).

Explicitly specifying the input parameters as `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]` solves the problem.

```
internal delegate bool dPathYetAnotherMakeUniqueName(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]System.Text.StringBuilder pszUniqueName, 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string pszPath,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string pszShort, 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string pszFileSpec);
```

The `CharSet = CharSet.Unicode` field in the `DllImport` attribute takes care of this for you, hence the difference.

**A more straightforward method** is to use the [`UnmanagedFunctionPointer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedfunctionpointerattribute(v=vs.100).aspx) attribute when declaring your delegate, and specify the proper `CharSet`. This more closely matches your `DllImport` declaration.

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Winapi, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
internal delegate bool dPathYetAnotherMakeUniqueName(
    System.Text.StringBuilder pszUniqueName, 
    string pszPath,
    string pszShort,
    string pszFileSpec);
```

---

More to the point, it doesn't seem like there is any reason to use `GetProcAddress` in this case. You already know the name of the dll in advance, you don't need to specify its full path, and you can guarantee that the dll will be found and that the function will be found within in. `DLLImport` already handles the situation perfectly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and explanation! That worked perfectly. Also, there is no practical reason to the two approaches, I am just trying things out in different ways for the novelty of it.